# Citrix Receiver - 13.2.1 - hangs forever

Tags: linux, strace, funtoo, citrix

I had Citrix Receiver working on funtoo linux a while back, but made some changes and could not figure for the life of me what it was.  I thought perhaps Funtoo was not stable or there was a conflict with the shared libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to install `strace` and the problem was this.  Citrix Receiver will happily wait indefinitely for the directory `~/.ICAClient` to exist before confirming if you accept the EULA because it wants to save your preferences.

Please make sure you do `mkdir -p ~/.ICAClient` and you'll be okay.